# Event Listener on element created with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, onchange

I am creating an input element inside my DOM using JavaScript whenever a button is created. I did this using "document.createElement('input')" then adding an event listener using "element.addEventListener('change', function())". This is inside a function inside a React component btw.

```
    const addChoice = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
    questionData.choices.push("");
    console.log(questionData.choices);

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'ans');
    input.setAttribute('id', `choice ${counter}`);
    input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
    input.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

    const check = document.createElement('input');
    check.type = "checkbox";
    check.id = `correctAnswer-${counter}`;
    check.name = "check";
    check.setAttribute('class','form-check-input');
    check.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

    div.id = `choice-div-${counter}`;
    div.className = "mb-3";
    div.innerHTML = `
    <label for="title" class="form-label">
      Ans ${counter}
    </label>
    `;
    div.appendChild(input);
    div.appendChild(check);
    div.innerHTML+=`
    <label class="form-check-label" for="correctAnswer-${counter}">
    Correct
    </label>`;
    const targetNode = document.getElementById('choices');
    targetNode.appendChild(div);
  };
```

Here is my code above. Both "input" and "check" elements are not calling the handleChange function whenever a change is made on them. I also tried changing the event listener to 'click' and the same issue pertains.
[This is an image of what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCQAK.png) I am trying to add another input element in the form and "on change" a function is called that would save to an array the choices entered.

Comment: Try changing it to `input`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing this instead of more "React-y" practices?

Comment: I mean, `change` is a legitimate event type.  OP, can you provide a bigger snippet of code, preferably as a StackSnippet or Codesandbox that we can run and observe the same issue you're having?  I don't see anything immediately with the code provided, but there are many things that could be going wrong in the surrounding code or even in the CSS.  Also agree with @vr. that this seems like a weird way to build a React component.

Comment: I am new in React so i find myself using javascript methods that might not always be the most effective methods of React.

Comment: i found that when i comment the "check" variable the event listener on the first element works fine. how??!

Comment: In react we don't really recommend using DOM manipulation, but instead use react logic and events to achieve the same results. But I am afraid that in order to help, We will need to know a bit more context. Can you tell us what you are trying to do here? is it a form you want to submit? Or should these inputs be created based on some data?